# get the variables inside the event at the time outside the listening event

Tags: javascript, events, button

consider function ‍`seletcolor()` below:

```
function seletcolor() {
    var button = document.querySelector("button");
    var a = 1;
    button.onclick = function (e) {
        a = a++;
    };
    console.log(a);
}
```

Once I click on button, I want to print out the value of the variable `a` inside the event outside the event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: why is that you are not adding console.log(a) inside the handler ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to print the value when they click, you need to put the `console.log` call inside the `onclick` function.

```
function seletcolor() {
    var button = document.querySelector("button");
    var a = 1;
    button.onclick = function (e) {
        a++;
        console.log(a);
    };
}
```

Also, to increment a variable it's just `a++`. That performs the assignment, you don't need to assign it back (which actually undoes the increment, because `a++` returns the old value).